# switch case for a variable values stored inside an array

Tags: visual-c++, switch-statement

Is there any method for writing a switch case for a variable where valued are stored inside an array. length of the array is not known during the compile time but during the runtime,

Comment: unfortunately, in C/C++ all cases must be constant and known at compile time. Also, C++ does not allow variable length array. C99 supports it but VC doesn't conform to C99 either

Comment: With a variable length of array you would have a variable number of code fragments (cases) that should be executed. How do you generate these code fragments at run-time? Probably you mean something else but didn't succeed to express your needs.